# Vector labels get cutted since new ol-version (3.12.1) and VectorTile layer

Tags: openlayers-3

Since i upgraded my application to ol.3.12.1 from ol.3.9.0 and implemented the new VectorTile Layer and Source i got some normal but bad rendering behaviour. The problem is that labels which are intersecting the tileborders get cut off. I looked ate the Sourcecode but i found no possibility to set an option, like partials or overlap like in other libaries which are working with tiles (mapserver or e.g). 
Does anyone know a Workaround? I looked at the pull request and it doesn't seem to be an issue right know. Screenshot attached.

FYI The GeoJson geometries are points, and the problem is a lable as a Text which get cut off.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you didn't use a buffer to generate your vector tiles?

Comment: I dont use any real middleware to create the tiles. Because the data is nearly real time - i access the geometries directly in the postgres-postgis db and related values. I'm using a php library to calculate the extend from the tilecoords and query the database, and generate a geojson foreach tile and sent it back to the ol library.

Answer (score 2):

When using [ol.source.VectorTile](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.VectorTile.html) geometries are clipped at the tile borders. Vector tiles are supposed to work with a [buffer](https://www.mapbox.com/help/source-manual/#buffers) to avoid rendering issues.

In your case, you probably want to use [ol.source.Vector](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html) with [ol.loadingstrategy.tile](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.loadingstrategy.html#.tile) as loading strategy.

Here is an example:
http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-osm.html

```
  var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
      var epsg4326Extent =
          ol.proj.transformExtent(extent, projection, 'EPSG:4326');
      return 'http://your-webservice?bbox=' +
          epsg4326Extent.join(',');
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
      maxZoom: 19
    }));
```

Make sure that your GeoJSON features have a proper identifier set, so that features are not inserted twice into the source (see [GeoJSON: Feature Objects](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects)).

Comment: Thanks, will try this approach, but the problem are not the geometries, in my example (screenshots) these are points (so there should be no cutoff)  with a strange styling, transparent fill and stroke. Normal these points are labeled with a text which contains information. When the label text crosses the tileborder ist gettin cut off. Actually no geometry problem. I will provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: If you follow @tsauerwein's suggestion to add a buffer around the tile extent when you fetch them, labelling will also work. Just make sure the buffer is big enough to the left and right, in case you have longer text in your labels.